# problem while hosting with subfolder react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, hosting, web-hosting

I created a app in react and hosted in `www.domain.com/party-booking`

for that my code for router is

`<BrowserRouter basename='/party-booking'>
            <App/>
 </BrowserRouter>`

and for routes.

```
<Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Dashboard}/>
        <Route path="/summary" exact component={Summary}/>
        <Route path="/thankyou" component={ThankYou}/>
        <Route component={NotFoundPage}/>
    </Switch>
```

now I am on `www.domain.com/party-booking/summary` and from I do payment,and on payment success I am currently redirecting to the

```
www.domain.com/party-booking/thankyou
```

now I want to redirect to below url instead of above one.

```
www.domain.com/thankyou
```

how to do this?Is it possible with same application or do I need to make other application??

Comment: So you want to redirect your user from `/party-booking/thankyou` to `/thankyou`?

Comment: @Michiel yes, you got it right..within same react application is it possible?

Comment: I assume that you are using `react-router-dom`?

Comment: yes, I have edited question, please have a look.yes I know about redirecting, but what my point is that I am hosting app in one sub url that is `www.domain.com/partybooking`, and for that I used 'basename' attribute https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string when I do `<Redirect to="/thankyou"/>` It redirects me to the `www.domain.com/partybooking/thankyou` not `www.domain.com/thankyou`

Comment: My answer contains the inforation how you should redirect.

Comment: but I have already hosted one application on `www.domain.com`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179178/discussion-between-tarang-and-michiel).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using `react-router-dom` (aka React Router V4)

Your core routing should look like this:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

<Router>
  <div>
    <Route path="/party-booking/thankyou" component={PartyBookingThankYou}/>
    <Route exact path="/party-booking" component={App}/>
    <Route exact path="/thankyou" component={ThankYou}/>
  </div>
</Router>
```

If you want to redirect a user to another route just return this component

```
<Redirect to="/thankyou"/>
```

More information about redirecting can be found here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect

More infirmation about routing can be found here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route